# Como ter Appwidgets em apphibrido?

Tags: android, ionic, widget

Tenho uma aplicação hibrida como posso colocar widgets nativos nela ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ter acesso a qualquer recurso nativo de um app híbrido você precisa de um plugin.

Como criar seus próprios plugins:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/

Lista de plugins Cordova: https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/

Lista de plugins que acessam recursos nativos no Ionic:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/